# Different Sidebar for same Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, sidebar

I am using a wordpress site with coupon theme i purchased it from fametheme. They used taxonomy to create store and coupons. In taxonomy (Store, Coupon) there are same sidebar. If i wrote in sidebar of any store then it will show in every store sidebar. How can i Change it?

Is there any option or WP Plugin to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a plugin which will show or hide a widget based on the taxonomy, page, post or categories.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/